# UI Router onExit transition hook

Tags: angular-ui-router

This code is triggering the promptForUnSavedChanges function twice on exiting the page.  How do I make it so that the prompt only displays once?

```
cleanupTransitionHook = $transitions.onExit({}, 
  promptForUnsavedChanges);

function promptForUnsavedChanges() {
    if (ctrl.forms.updateRecipe.$dirty || ctrl.changedPortionCount) {
      if ($window.confirm('You will lose unsaved changes if you leave this page')) {
        if (ctrl.changedPortionCount) {
          ctrl.recipeModel.updateCurrentUserMetaPortionSizeRatio(ctrl.originalScaleFactor, ctrl.userRanges);
        }
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe detect what state is exited. Your described problem sounds like you are entering one new state before actually leaving the page, therefore the promptForUnsavedChanges is fired two times, one time for every state exit.

Answer (score 0):

$transitions.onExit function return is deleter function.

so you call that function before return true

ex) cleanupTransitionHook();